# yii2 find returns null

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Why does findone() returns all public property as null.

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord 
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;


    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        $result =  static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
        var_dump($result);
        return $result;
    }
```

This returns

```
object(app\models\User)[81]
  public 'id' => null
  public 'username' => null
  public 'password' => null
  public 'authKey' => null
  public 'accessToken' => null
  private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 1
      'username' => string 'admin' (length=5)
      'password' => string '123456' (length=6)
      'auth_key' => string 'jkkk' (length=4)
      'created' => null
      'modified' => null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply remove db attributes from your model :

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord 
{

    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        ....
```

> Yii automatically defines an attribute in Active Record for every column of the associated table. **You should NOT redeclare any of the attributes**.

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html